# Where are the KDE Plasmashell logs?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, plasma, plasma5

I have an Ubuntu machine on which I installed KDE and since day 1 the plasmashell process was leaking memory and my panels just became extremely unresponsive over time. 
Now I would like to check the logs to see if I can find the cause, but I just don't know where they could be. I checked `/var/log` for a kde or plasmashell directory and I also checked `~/.kde` for any sorts of logs, but I couldn't find any. I also checked `dmesg` and `journalctl`. The latter had some lines about `KScreen`, but that's about it.

Does KDE/plasmashell even log anything? If so where can I find it?

Answer (score 7):

You should use journalctl...one of the best things about systemd is that all the logs are in one place...gone are the days of searching for files.

try:

```
journalctl -f | grep --line-buffered kde
```

I also recomend **[this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs)** article. Shows all the great things you can do with jounralctl.

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be more relevant output in `/home/user/.xsession-errors`
This file doesn't have timestamps, except at the start of a session, which looks like:

```
Xsession: X session started for user at vr 26 jun 2020 14:29:13 CEST
```

The content of this file doesn't appear in my `journalctl`, so no: not all the logs are in one place.

EDIT: at least this is the case on Kubuntu, in Manjaro KDE the xsession messages *are* integrated in journalctl after all

Comment: If your login manager is sddm, I found (on my system, an Artix install) that it can keep additional per-user logs in the `$HOME/.local/share/sddm` directory.